# Is calling findAll in a route's model done asynchronously?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model in my route as like this:

```
 model: function () {
        return {
            "first-levels":this.get('store').findAll('student')
        };
    }
```

Is findAll called, by default, asynchronously or synchronously? Can the default behavior be overridden?

Answer (score 4):

If you return normal object then model hook will not wait for the Promises to resove, so it will return immediately.

```
model: function () {
        return {
            "first-levels":this.get('store').findAll('student')
        };
    }
```

But if you return it like the below, then model hook will wait for Promise to resolve,

```
model: function () {
    return this.get('store').findAll('student');
}
```

Note: `findAll` will get the result from store and return immediately and in background, it will ask for adapter to fetch it again and update the store. this behaviour can be controlled by using `this.get('store').findAll('student',{reload:true})` For more details refer [findAll api guide](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findAll)

Comment: As far as I know both of them are alike (ways you have return the model) because in both case ultimately we return  this.get('store').findAll('student'); only the format is different.(eg:when you calling it from handlebar the first one would call as model.first-levels then will equal to  model in second way of calling)

Comment: Read this ember guide explanation https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/  `Typically, the model hook should return an Ember Data record, but it can also return any promise object (Ember Data records are promises), or a plain JavaScript object or array. Ember will wait until the data finishes loading (until the promise is resolved) before rendering the template.`

Comment: does this simply mean when I call to this.get('store').findAll('student') it is  always actually a asynchronous call where it will run on background, but until that data fetch get completed(until the promise is resolved) the template won't render.